# How do i evaluate this sum $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2n!}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

How do I evaluate this sum:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2n!}$$

**Note**: The series converges by the ratio test. I have tried to use this sum:$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}= \ln (2) $$ but I didn't succeed. Might there be others techniques which I don't know?

Thank you for any help

Comment: Have you tried to differentiate you series for $\ln(x)$?

Comment: it is a good idea if i don't have n!

Comment: A better idea would be to start with the series for $e^x-1$ instead of the series for $\ln x$, as that would give you the $n!$ in the numerator. Of course, it may be futile since [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28-1%29%5E%28n%2B1%29%2F%28n%5E2*n%21%29+from+n+%3D+1+to+infinity) doesn't give a nice closed form.

Comment: I can turn the sum into an integral like this: $$\int_0^1 du \, \int_0^1 dv \, \frac{1-e^{-u v}}{u v} $$ Not sure what good this does.

Comment: Setting $f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n^2n!}$, you can differentiate twice and come up with the second order ODE$$x^2f''(x)-xf'(x)+f(x)=x(e^x-1)$$which you can then try approaching with a power series solution via the Frobenius method. Mathematica returns a solution that agrees with the exact value of the series in terms of the [generalized hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html).

Comment: There is no reason to suppose it has a nice closed form, but it converges faster than an exponential function and the sum of the first $15$ terms show it is marginally greater than $0.8912127981113$

Comment: Numerical value: https://oeis.org/A367732 .

Answer (score 4):

We have that
$$ \frac{1}{n^2}=\int_{0}^{1}(-\log x)\,x^{n-1}\,dx \tag{1}$$
hence:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2 n!}=\int_{0}^{1}(-\log x)\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1} x^{n-1}}{n!}\,dx =\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}(-\log x)\,dx\tag{2}$$
and
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2 n!}=\frac{d}{d\alpha}\left.\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x^\alpha}\,dx\,\right|_{\alpha=1}\tag{3}$$
is a value of the derivative of a sum of an exponential integral function and a $\Gamma$ function.
The series definition directly implies that
$$  \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2 n!}= \phantom{}_3 F_3\left(1,1,1;2,2,2;-1\right).\tag{4}$$